# Using package genealogytree, how do I make invisible a particular line connecting two nodes?

Tags: node-connections, genealogy

Using the genealogytree package, I am combining trees that span several generations. One of the trees has no-one in the first generation, so I've used a g[phantom] to keep the positioning correct. This makes Gen1 (in the MWE below) invisible, but the connecting line between the invisible Gen 1 and the visible Gen2 is also visible.
How can I remove / make invisible the line above Gen2M?
[image: How can I remove / make invisible the line above Gen2M?]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\gtrset{processing=tcbox*}

\genealogytree
{
child
    {
    g[phantom*]{Gen1}
        child
        {
        g[male]         {Gen2M}
        p[female]       {Gen2F}
        }
    }   
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please have a look at the answer if it meets the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following syntax to disconnect the line/ edge

```
g[disconnect,phantom*]{Gen1}
```

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\gtrset{processing=tcbox*}

\genealogytree
{
child
    {
    g[disconnect,phantom*]{Gen1}
        child
        {
        g[male]         {Gen2M}
        p[female]       {Gen2F}
        }
    }   
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```